# How to include more outcomes on Infer.NET's BPM?

Tags: machine-learning

How can I modify [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/infernet)'s [Tutorial 4: Bayes Point Machine](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/Bayes%20Point%20Machine%20tutorial.aspx) to include more outcomes?

For example, how can I add willRent and get the separate probabilities for willBuy and willRent?

```
        double[] incomes = { 63, 16, 28, 55, 22, 20 };
        double[] ages = { 38, 23, 40, 27, 18, 40 };
        bool[] willBuy = { true, false, true, true, false, false };
        bool[] willRent = { false, false, true, false, true, false };
```

Edit - Here's the example in copy/paste format:

```
static void Main()
{
    double[] incomes = { 63, 16, 28, 55, 22, 20 };
    double[] ages = { 38, 23, 40, 27, 18, 40 };
    bool[] willBuy = { true, false, true, true, false, false };

    // Create x vector, augmented by 1
    Vector[] xdata = new Vector[incomes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < xdata.Length; i++)
        xdata[i] = Vector.FromArray(incomes[i], ages[i], 1);
    VariableArray<Vector> x = Variable.Observed(xdata);

    // Create target y
    VariableArray<bool> y = Variable.Observed(willBuy, x.Range);

    Variable<Vector> w = Variable.Random(new VectorGaussian(Vector.Zero(3), PositiveDefiniteMatrix.Identity(3)));
    Range j = y.Range;
    double noise = 0.1;
    y[j] = Variable.GaussianFromMeanAndVariance(Variable.InnerProduct(w, x[j]), noise) > 0;

    InferenceEngine engine = new InferenceEngine(new ExpectationPropagation());
    VectorGaussian wPosterior = engine.Infer<VectorGaussian>(w);
    Console.WriteLine("Dist over w=\n" + wPosterior);

    double[] incomesTest = { 58, 18, 22 };
    double[] agesTest = { 36, 24, 37 };
    VariableArray<bool> ytest = Variable.Array<bool>(new Range(agesTest.Length));
    BayesPointMachine(incomesTest, agesTest, Variable.Random(wPosterior), ytest);
    Console.WriteLine("output=\n" + engine.Infer(ytest));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void BayesPointMachine(double[] incomes,double[] ages,Variable<Vector> w,VariableArray<bool> y)
{
    // Create x vector, augmented by 1
    Range j = y.Range;
    Vector[] xdata = new Vector[incomes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < xdata.Length; i++)
        xdata[i] = Vector.FromArray(incomes[i], ages[i], 1);
    VariableArray<Vector> x = Variable.Observed(xdata, j);

    // Bayes Point Machine
    double noise = 0.1;
    y[j] = Variable.GaussianFromMeanAndVariance(Variable.InnerProduct(w, x[j]), noise) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 variables here.

```
                   Will Buy?
                  ^        ^
                 /          \
                Age        Income
                 \          /
                  v        v
                   Will Rent?
```

Given `(Age,Income)`, `Will Buy` and `Will Rent` are independent variables, i.e., [conditional independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence).

So that you could just construct two separate Bayes Point Machines:

- One for `Age`, `Income` and `Will Rent`.
- One for `Age`, `Income` and `Will Buy`.

Comment: With my data set it already takes a very long time to do one pass. I'll be calculating the probabilities for many outcomes. Doing the operation for every outcome is not practical. I'm trying to get the probabilities for all outcomes in one shot.

Comment: If your `outcomes` are all conditionally independent on the same set of variables (like the `age` and `income` here), how could you possibly improve your run time performance by including them in the same graphical model?